# Raw data extraction according to a documentation

Tags: javascript, parsing, extract

I have to extract data from a raw hex string, like this : 800200217fff8000bf5e0000 
As you can see, my data have 12 bytes, so according to this, i looking for solution on the web, and i found this solution :

```
var s = "800200217fff8000bf5e0000"
var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i+=2)
{
    result.push(parseInt(s.substring(i, i + 2), 16));
}

result = Uint8Array.from(result)
```

So now, i have :

800200217fff8000bf5e0000 => 128,2,0,33,127,255,128,0,191,94,0,0

It's a good point. But now, i'm in trouble with the data extraction. According to the documentation of the device who sent the frame, i read this, in description on the first byte :

Bit     |   Name        |   Description

7   |   Parking slot status|    0 -> empty, 1 -> occupied

6   |   Battery state   |   0 -> good level, 1 -> bad level

5-4 |   Reserved    |   Do not consider

3-2-1-0 |   Frame type  |   0- info frame, 1- Keep alive frame etc...

So that's good that i have 128 for my first byte, but i don't really think it will help me a lot. I have a solution, like divide by 128, 64, 32 etc and found for each if the bit is 1 or 0, but i don't think it's a good solution.

Do you know a great way to perform my data parsing good ?

Comment: hint (value & 2^n) returns nonzero if bit n is set, example `var bit7set = (value & 128) > 0;`  See [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Comment: Ah yes, great ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators):

```
var parking_slot_status = result[0] & 1;
var battery_state = result[0] & 2;
```

To get the 7th bit use the mask `0x00000001` (1), to get the 6th bit use `0x00000010` (2) and so on.